# How to configure mammoth library in Angular project which is made with Angular CLI and uses webpack 5

Tags: angular, mammoth

I need a functionality that can convert uploaded file (mostly .docx) content to HTML code. I thought of using the "mammoth" library.

I can't seem to configure my project so that it can use the "mammoth". Does anybody know what should I do to make it possible?

I have cleared all the compilation errors and when I build the project then it compiles fine. However, if I try to load the page I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at 50074 (util.js:109:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 6027 (html-writer.js:1:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 90765 (index.js:1:18)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 20133 (document-to-html.js:9:15)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 88933 (index.js:5:25)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 61735 (menu.component.html:5:26)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 34283 (document-list.component.html:3:47)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
at 32418 (exercises.component.html:3:46)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
```

Has anybody had experience using "mammoth" in Angular lately? How did you configure it?

I've found that maybe I should edit my "polyfills.ts" file but I can't find it since Angular CLI hides it and makes it uneditable for me. When I try to create my own polyfills.ts file I run into all kinds of import errors. If that's the case then can somebody provide me the content of polyfills.ts and how do I configure my project to use my file and not the Angular CLI one? All help is appreciated. I provided some file contents of the current state of the project.

## My custom-webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");


module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify")
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ],
}
```

## My angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/app/document-toolbar/ng-multiselect-dropdown.theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularCustomWebpackConfig:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "mammoth": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.9",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "webpack": "^5.76.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

## My tsconfig.app.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?  if so please post it.  Looks like a lot of people are looking.